# 2d map: how to manage it?

Tags: design-patterns, tiles, maps, level-design

i'm developing a 2d game (top down), and i'm a beginner. 
Now, i've to create a map, with object (to interact with) ... 
I don't know how to .. manage the problem ! 
Does anyone can help me ? What are the methodology used ?
Thanks

Comment: What programming language are you using? Knowing this will allow people to provide answers and code snippets that are easier for you to understand.

Comment: I'm using C#, but i can understand other "major" languages ;)!

Comment: Have a look at the 2D Level design/editing/saving question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3107/450

Answer (score 5):

I answered with the following for [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/your-recommendation-for-path-construction-from-a-single-background-image). If you look for tutorials for using these technologies, you should be able to get started or at least have other more detailed questions.

Two programs you should at least take a look at are [**Mappy**](http://tilemap.co.uk/mappy.php) and [**Tiled**](http://www.mapeditor.org/). A library for XNA integration with Tiled called **TiledLib** was been developed and could have bene of some use, if only to take a look at for ideas, but no longer appears to be available.